# "Cannot pass immutable value to mutating operator: 'i' is a 'let' constant" in struct

Tags: swift, struct

Why the function with increasing `i` value gives me an error:

> Cannot pass immutable value to mutating operator: 'i' is a 'let'
>   constant

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit 
/* initialising the struct to store values in array and change them 
with function*/
struct DayMenu {
/* declaring the variables of menu for breakfast, lunch and dinner*/
let breakfast = "egg"
let lunch = ["orange", "apple", "meat"]
let dinner = ["veggi", "juice", "pasta"]
/* creating a function which changes the value by increasing the index 
of the array by 1*/
func showMenu(_:String, _:String, _:String)->String {
    var i:Int=0
    for i in 0...dinner.count {
        for i in 0...lunch.count {
            return lunch[i]
            dinner[i]
            i++ 
/* increasing the index by 1*/
error Cannot pass immutable value to mutating operator: i is a 'let' 
constant*/
        }}}}
let dinnerForToday = DayMenu()
let whatToEat = dinnerForToday.showMenu
```

Comment: First, write down what you want from the showMenu method, because there are also problems ...

Comment: For starters., the lines `var i:Int=0` & `i++` are pointless. `for in` loops handle that scenario automatically. Secondly, you should use different iterators for your nested loops. **Note:** 3 dots in a `for in` loop means include upper bound. You might want to use `for i in 0..<dinner.count`

Answer (score 1):

Use `while` instead of `for`
You cannot change `i` which is an iterator.

`var i:Int = 0` is useless in your code
`i++` is not used in Swift. Use `i += 1`

You use wrong `i` key for both loops. For instance, use `i` and `j`.

Sample:

```
//external loop
        var i = 0
        while i < dinner.count {
            i += 1

            //your logic

            //internal loop
            var j = 0
            while j < lunch.count {
                j += 1

                //you logic
            }
        }
```

Comment: For a fixed number of iterations never use `while`, that’s a bad suggestion. In a `for` loop you get the increment of the index for free. And fast enumeration, as the name implies, is pretty fast.

Comment: @vadian he says  he wants changing iterator inside the loop

Comment: Then use [stride](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641347-stride). It's still better than `while`.

Comment: @vadian thanks for the suggestion. Being a telepath I see that he wants using the complicated logic:) Stride is useful, yep.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, your method `showMenu` is a mess.

You cannot increment the index variable of a `for` loop, that's what the error message says.
But the point is you **must not** increment the index variable of a `for` loop, because the `for` loop does it automatically.

If you need a different increment step as 1 use `stride`.

Other issues:

- In the code the incremental line is not even reached at runtime, because you will return the first lunch while exiting the method.
- The outer repeat loop is pointless
- The three parameters, which have no parameters labels by the way are unused.
- Your syntax `for i in 0...dinner.count` can cause an exception because for example in an array with one item the range is `0...1` (2 indexes), but there is only one item.
- A return value at the end of the method is missing.

Your method compiles with this syntax

```
func showMenu() -> String {
    for i in stride(from: 0, to: dinner.count, by: 2) {
        for j in stride(from: 0, to: lunch.count, by: 2) {
            return lunch[j]
            // dinner[i]
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

However in practice the method does just this:

```
func showMenu() -> String {
     return lunch[0]
}
```